# Derivation of Complex Fourier Series coefficients through inner products (and swapping arugments)

Tags: fourier-series, inner-products, fourier-transform, eigenfunctions, sturm-liouville

I am trying to derive the complex Fourier series coefficients given by:$$f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}{c_n}e^{inx}$$ with coefficients:$$c_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{f(x)}e^{-inx}dx$$

I am trying to use the inner product defined as:
$$\lt f,g\gt\,\,=\int_a^b{f(x)\overline{g(x)}dx}$$
to find this. I know that $\lt f,g\gt \neq \lt g,f\gt$ if $f$ and $g$ are complex. I have no problem finding generalized Fourier series when my eigenfunctions are real like in trigonometric Fourier series. I am trying to apply to complex Fourier series the approach I learned from Sturm-Liouville theory where I wrote functions as an eigenfunction expansion.

I often see that from this inner product is used with the arguments in this order for the definition of the complex Fourier coefficient:  $$c_n=\frac{\lt f,e^{inx} \gt}{\lt e^{inx},e^{inx} \gt}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{f(x)}e^{-inx}dx$$.

It seems that you can instead take: $$a_n=\frac{\lt e^{inx},f \gt}{\lt e^{inx},e^{inx} \gt}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{inx}\overline{f(x)}dx$$ (the inner product arguments flipped) and still create a "valid" complex fourier series. The choice to order the inner product with the exponential term being conjugated due to the inner product seems arbitrary.

Using the new definition for $c_n$ above (as $a_n$), it seems that this a valid series for $f$:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}{a_n}e^{-inx}$$

with coefficients:$$a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{inx}\overline{f(x)}dx$$

This appears to just flip the series upside down.

Now to my question: It seems arbitrary to me that $c_n$ corresponds to $e^{inx}$ whereas $a_n$ corresponds to $e^{-inx}$. Why can't it be the other way around? Why is the correspondence between $c_n$ and $e^{inx}$ drawn in the first place?

In essence, why would the series:$$f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}{a_n}e^{inx}$$

with coefficients:$$a_n=\frac{\lt e^{inx},f \gt}{\lt e^{inx},e^{inx} \gt}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{inx}\overline{f(x)}dx$$

be invalid?

Comment: In your definition of $a_n$, the right side doesn't agree with your definition of the inner product. The $f$, the second factor, is supposed to be conjugated.

Comment: good catch I'll edit that. I went into it assume that f was real but I didn't explicitly state that

Comment: Apart from that, it is likely that all you are looking at is at reversing the order of the coefficients. $a_{-n}=c_n$.

Comment: That's what I notice seems to be happening. But I am wondering why the correspondence between $c_n$ and the eigenfunction (if it's even called that in this case) $e^{inx}$ is made in the first place?

Comment: From what I understand, when I expanded functions using sturm liouville theory, the summations were from 0 to infinity so there was a clear correspondence between coefficients and eigenfunctions. I'm confused on how this translates (if it does) to complex fourier series where the series runs from minus to plus infinity

Comment: I have edited the question to make the intention more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the functions $\{e_n(x) := e^{inx}\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ form an orthogonal basis of $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$. In consequence, the Fourier series of a function $f$ is nothing else than the representation of $f$ in the said basis, i.e. $f(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} c_n e_n(x)$, where the coefficients $c_n$ play the role of its components, which are themselves given by the orthogonal projection of $f$ on $e_n$. In other words, if $P_n := \frac{e_ne_n^\dagger}{e_n^\dagger e_n}$ represents the associated orthogonal projector, then one gets
$$
c_n 
   = \frac{e_n^\dagger f}{e_n^\dagger e_n} 
   = \frac{\langle e_n,f \rangle}{\langle e_n,e_n \rangle} 
   = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e_n(x)^*f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x 
   = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\,e^{-inx} \,\mathrm{d}x,
$$
and not the reverse formula you proposed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Is the function that you take the conjugate of interpreted as the function that you are projecting onto? So in other words, with a inner product acting on complex valued functions, projecting $f$ onto $g$ not the same as $g$ onto $f$?

Comment: @alephnull14177  First question : yes. Second question : yes, because a complex inner product is not symmetric (it is sesquilinear form instead of a bilinear one).

Comment: What is the Intuition for why you have to take the conjugate of why you are projecting on? I understand why the conjugate exists in the definition so that the norm is real, but I don’t understand what it means intuitively.

Comment: @alephnull14177  The idea comes from the so-called closure/completeness relation, satisfied by orthonormal basis (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis#Basic_formula for instance). It means that the operator $I = \displaystyle \sum_k e_ke_k^\dagger$ corresponds to the identity matrix, so that $$f = If = \sum_k e_ke_k^\dagger f = \sum_k \langle e_k,f \rangle e_k$$.